# Awk printing only strings before variables and strings

Tags: bash, macos, awk, printing, macos-sierra

I'm trying to turn data from the last command into epoch time using the awk print. the code works on 10.14.5 all the time, and works on 10.13.6 some of the time. When I came into work this morning it worked fine, then around 11 started giving me errors.

Basically, awk is printing literal strings, then a newline character, then the literal strings and the variables as it should. for example, 
if $1="Hello", then:

```sh
awk '{print $1,"World"}'
```

is actually printing "World
Hello World"

the actual line of code giving the error is this:

```sh
x=$(last -1 $a | awk '{print $3 " "$4 " " $5  " " $6 ":00 EDT "}')
```

where it should be setting x to "Fri May 31 12:43:00 EDT " for example, it is setting x to " :00 EDT
Fri May 31 12:43:00 EDT "

EDIT: I should say that the $a in the line of code would be set to a username on the computer

Comment: Sounds like you have DOS line endings. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it?noredirect=1#comment97778025_45772525

Comment: Are you sure `last` is printing what you expect?

Comment: On my High Sierra system `last` doesn't show anything except `wtmp begins Fri May 31 12:48`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my High Sierra system, `last -1 barmar` doesn't print any useful information. My Mac has been up for 9 days (since I installed the most recent security update). It takes 8 seconds to run, and just prints:

```
wtmp begins Fri May 31 12:53
```

So there's a blank line and then the line saying where `wtmp` begins, which always seems to be the current time.

So the `awk` script is working correctly. The first line doesn't have any fields, so all the `$n` values will be empty, and you get just `:00 EDT`. The second line contains the `wtmp begins` line, and that creates `Fri May 31 12:48:00 EDT` in the output (even though you used `-1`, it still produces two lines of output). When you combine them, you get

```
$ echo "$x"
   :00 EDT 
Fri May 31 12:48:00 EDT
```

[Terminal 'last' command doesn't display login history](https://superuser.com/questions/1024867/terminal-last-command-doesnt-display-login-history) claims that `sudo last` should work, but it doesn't for me.

[How do you stop wtmp from erasing?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206081/how-do-you-stop-wtmp-from-erasing) suggests getting the information you want from `/var/log/monthly.out`.

Comment: Thank you. My 10.13 machine is doing the same thing. Do you know why last would work some times and not others? When I was testing this morning the last command worked fine then around 11 am it stopped working and hasn't worked since. When i tested on 68 machines yesterday the last command worked on about 40% of them, and many of those were running 10.13

Comment: I think there's a periodic job that empties the wtmp file. So your first try was before the file was cleaned.